# Access a menu item of an Activity in a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

I'm new to Android. I have an Activity and it has a fragment and bottomnavigationview which is bound to a set of menus. I want to capture the menu item clicked event in the fragment. How to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/todo_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ViewModel must not capture anything View-related or it will leak your Activity/Fragment. You should invert your design so the Activity or Fragment notifies the ViewModel on these events.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You're right. I actually want to access it in the fragment, not in its viewmodel. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity. Make BottomNavigationView public

```
public BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
```

In Fragment, Access BottomNavigationView and do whatever you like with it.

```
if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
        // get Main Activity
        activity = (Main) getActivity();
     
         // Do what you want to do with bottom Navigation
        activity.BottomNavigationView 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a single Activity for the app named MainActivity. Since I know it is the only activity associated with any Fragment in the app, it's safe to make it into an extension property. Like `requireActivity()`, you can only use it while the Fragment is attached.

```
val Fragment.mainActivity: MainActivity get() = requireActivity() as MainActivity
```

Then if you're using a NavController you can add a listener, but you need to remember to remove it when the Fragment is detached so the Fragment isn't leaked to the NavController and the listener isn't still getting called when the Fragment is detached.

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(), NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //...
        mainActivity.navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mainActivity.navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onDestinationChanged(
        controller: NavController,
        destination: NavDestination,
        arguments: Bundle?
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for an elegant solution about navigations use Navigation UI framework. Here is the official documentation: [Bottom Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation)

**To answer your question:**

```
interface BottomNavigationListener{
   onButtonOneClicked(View yourOptionalArgument)
   onButtonOneClicked(View yourOptionalArgument)
}
```

- extend it from `MainFragment : Fragment, BottomNavigationListener` (and implement required)

in your activity ; create a property of type BottomNavigationListener:

```
var bottomNavListener: BottomNavigationListener?
```

initialize it once you have access to your fragment, and remove it in `onDestroy()`

```
override fun onCreate(){
    val mainFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag):MainFragment
    // requires you to set tag in your MainFragment first
    bottomNavListener = mainFragment
}

override fun onDestroy(){
    bottomNavListener = null
}
```

when calling onClickListener from BottomBarItems in Activity, call the corresponding functions:

```
bottomBarButtonOne.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    bottomNavListener.onButtonOneClicked(v);
    // do stuff here
}
```